polaris-style connecters in outdoor/damp location
I need to splice a 4/0 AL feeder and extend it (as 3/0 CU).   It lives in a disconnect panel which is rated NEMA 3R, which is mounted outside on a shed.
It's unclear to me whether I can use Polaris-Black style connectors or similar.   I see that there are direct-burial connectors but these are extremely bulky and seem overkill.   The disconnect panel itself has breakers and bus bars that don't seem to be as robust as a Polaris connector.
Advice?

Why are you extending it with copper wire instead of more aluminum?  Are you trying to interface to a badly designed thing that can't handle aluminum wire?

I’m extending it to an EG4 GridBoss which ties to my solar/battery inverter.   Technically I could feed AL to the breaker in the GridBoss but I was hoping to pass the 5 conductors I need in one 2” conduit.  I can do that with 3/0 but not 4/0.

Ah, fair enough re:conduit fill then

Yes, Polaris style connectors are fine in a 3R cabinet.
There may be capacity or other issues depending on exact application.
